# A piston of mass $m$ undergoes simple harmonic motion Subjected to Two Forces

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

> A  piston  of  mass $m$ undergoes  simple  harmonic  motion $x(t)=\cos(w)$.  The piston is  subject  to two forces: a driving force $_{}$ and a friction force $F_F$, written as $_{}()=_D\cos(+)$ and $_f()=−_x$ where $_$ is the velocity of the piston and $$ is a constant. Force balance at constant velocity requires that $_{}+_=_$ where $_$ is the acceleration of the piston. If $=1.00\ \mathrm{kg}$, $=200\ \mathrm{rad/s}$, $ =100\ \mathrm{kg/s}$, what drive force $F_D$ will result in an amplitude displacement $=10.0\ \mathrm{cm}$?

Based on what is given I can setup the following differential equation:

$$F_D\cos(wt + \phi) - \gamma \dot{x} = m \ddot{x} \rightarrow \ddot{x} + \frac{\gamma}{m}\dot{x} = \frac{F_D}{m}\cos(wt+\phi)$$

The question says it goes under simply harmonic motion so I assume a possible solution to be $x = A\cos(wt)$. Substituting $x, \dot{x}, \ddot{x}$ into the differential equation:

$$-Aw^2\cos(wt) + \frac{\gamma}{m} (-Aw\sin(wt)) = \frac{F_D}{m} (\cos(wt)\cos(\phi) - \sin(wt)\sin(\phi))$$

From here, I can match the cosines and sines to generate the following two equations:

$$-Aw^2 = \frac{F_D}{m}\cos(\phi)$$
$$\frac{-A\gamma w}{m} = \sin(\phi)\frac{F_D}{M}$$

From here I have two equations and two unknowns, thus $F_D$ and $\phi$ can both be solved for.

$$\tan(\phi) = \frac{\gamma}{mw}, \phi = 0.4626, 3.6$$

I am suppose to be getting an angle of $2.67$. Can someone explain the flaw in logic here?

Comment: Is 2.67 in radians or degrees? Your answer is very close to 26.7 degrees.

Comment: My bad, 153 deg or 2.67 rad

Comment: Your equations say both sin and cos of phi are negative, which puts you in quadrant 3. That still will not get your preferred answer, but you might recheck your signs and make you are in the correct quadrant.

Comment: Ah the sine should not be negative, then the answer works out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second equation is missing a (-) sign from the right-hand side =>

$$ \frac{-A\gamma w}{m} = -\sin(\phi)\frac{F_D}{M} $$

This means that

$$ \tan\phi = \frac{F_D \sin \phi}{F_D \cos \phi} = \frac{A \gamma \omega}{-A m \omega^2} = -\frac{ \gamma}{m \omega} $$